# No pages in Classic ASP site will load after entering some code on a single page

Tags: asp-classic

This site was working properly before I started encountering an error after entering some code. The code was not on the home page but none of the site pages will load now. I restarted the site in IIS and that did not help.

Here is the code that I entered:

```vbs
'Prepare to parse XML
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject(Microsoft.XMLDOM)

'Set Asynchoronous = false
objXML.async = False

'Load the XML file.
'User Server.MapPath method is the XML is located in your site.
'Else you can use the absolute path.
objXML.Load (Server.MapPath(Products.xml))

'If there is any errors pasring the file the notify
If objXML.parseError.errorCode = 0 Then        
    'Response.Write(objXML.parseError.reason)
Else objXML.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
    'Get ALL the Elements by the tag name product
    Set products = objXML.getElementsByTagName(product)

    Select Case iItemID
        Case 1
            aParameters = Array(products.item(0).childNodes(0).text, products.item(i).childNodes(2).text, products.item(i).childNodes(2).text)
        Case 2
            aParameters = Array(products.item(1).childNodes(0).text, products.item(i).childNodes(2).text, products.item(i).childNodes(2).text)        
    End Select

    ' Return array containing product info.
    GetItemParameters = aParameters
End If
```

Running IIS in Windows 7 using classic ASP. Editing with Notepad++.

Here is the XML file:

```xml
<configuration>
<products>
    <product>   
        <image>
            <![CDATA[ /Images/Atlas Gloves.jpg ]]>
        </image>    
        <name>
            <![CDATA[ Atlas Nitrile Touch Gloves ]]>
        </name>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[ Atlas Nitrile Touch is available in 6 vibrant colors, and is America’s #1 glove for the Lawn and Garden market. Atlas gloves have a breathable nylon back and are machine washable. Like a “second skin,” these gloves are the most comfortable! Atlas Nitrile gloves are the #1 gardening gloves. Atlas Nitrile gloves act like a "second skin" between the user and their work, offering full dexterity and grip. Atlas Nitrile Gloves are perfect for gardening, but their uses expand to so many places – the woodshop, the workshop, the workplace. ]]>
        </description>
        <size>
            <![CDATA[ Small, Medium ]]>
        </size>
        <color>
            <![CDATA[ Purple, Pink, Green, Orange ]]>
        </color>
    </product>
</products>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The actual error message would help.

Comment: I am not receiving an error message. It just never loads.

Comment: Look at your server log.

Comment: I checked the server log, but it stopped just prior to this happening with no error messages. I could see error messages from earlier in the day so it was logging but apparently this stopped it cold.

In the end, I had to restart the App Pool in IIS. I had restarted the site previously and everything was shown as running. After restarting the App Pool it came right back up.

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @Darren: Do you have server-side debugging turned on?  If so turn it off.  You can then fix this code.  If you add to the question a sample of your products.xml someone might kindly show you how you should have written the function.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will add the XML to my initial post.

Comment: Have you tried putting `Microsoft.XMLDOM` in quotes? `Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")`

Comment: I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start by getting the code in order:

First we'll create a little helper function which given a parent XML element and an XPath (can be simply a tagName of a child element) will return the text value of an element.  In this case I have deliberately choosen to return null if the element isn't found but you could leave the return value empty if you prefer:

```
Function GetElemText(parentElem, path)
     Dim elem: Set elem = parentElem.selectSingleNode(path)
     If Not elem Is Nothing Then
         GetElemText = elem.text
     Else
         GetElemText = null
     End If
End Function
```

Now we'll create a little VBScript class which has a field for each of the product elements.  This class has a `LoadFromXml` method which given an product xml element will extract the field values.

```
Class Product

    Public Image
    Public Name
    Public Description
    Public Size
    Public Color

    Public Sub LoadFromXml(prodElem)
         Image = GetElemText(prodElem, "image")
         Name = GetElemText(prodElem, "name")
         Description = GetElemText(prodElem, "description")
         Size = GetElemText(prodElem, "size")
         Color = GetElemText(prodElem, "color")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Finally we create a `GetProduct` function that given the index of a product will load return a `Product` class instance loaded with the appropriate product details.

```
Function GetProduct(productIndex)

    Dim objXML: Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0") 

    objXML.async = False 
    objXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    objXML.Load Server.MapPath("Products.xml") ''# Assumes Products xml in same folder as this script 

    Dim elem: Set elem = objXML.documentElement.selectSingleNode("products/product[" & productIndex & "]") 
    If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        Set GetProduct = new Product
        GetProduct.LoadFromXml elem
    Else
        Set GetProduct = Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

Note the use named elements eliminates the need for "magic numbers" the values of which you would either have to remember or place in constants and are very fragile.  Also the use of XPath as the selection language and a more specific ProgID.  All in all much more robust and in this case also working.

If your products xml remains fairly static over the life time of the application consider this variation of:

```
Function GetProduct(productIndex)

    Dim objXML
    If IsEmpty(Application.Contents("Products")) Then
        Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0") 
        objXML.async = False 
        objXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        Set Application.Contents("Products") = objXML
    Else
        Set objXML = Application.Contents("Products")
    End If

    objXML.Load Server.MapPath("Products.xml") ''# Assumes Products xml in same folder as this script 

    Dim elem: Set elem = objXML.documentElement.selectSingleNode("products/product[" & productIndex & "]") 
    If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        Set GetProduct = new Product
        GetProduct.LoadFromXml elem
    Else
        Set GetProduct = Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

This loads the XML DOM into the application store saving the cost of reloading every time a product is needed.

One other change I would recommend, the reliance of know the ordinal position of a product element in order to retrieve it is quite fragile.  Consider adding an `id="1"` attribute to the product element.  It can then be retrieved with:

```
    Dim elem: Set elem = objXML.documentElement.selectSingleNode("products/product[@id=""" & productIndex & """]")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the post. Unfortunately, I won't be able to check it until in the morning.